# Add sequence number to split comma separated values in new rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following set of data:

```
Col A    Col B
Prod1    SKU-A, SKU-B
Prod2    SKU-C, SKU-D, SKU-E
```

I need this outputted as:

```
Col A    Col B    Col C
Prod1    SKU-A      1
Prod1    SKU-B      2
Prod2    SKU-C      1
Prod2    SKU-D      2
Prod2    SKU-E      3
```

Basically i need to split the comma separated values in column B into separate rows, which i think i can do via various macros available on this site, **however** i need to add (another) column C that assigns a numeric sequence to each split row for every Product given in column A.

I hope this makes sense!

**EDIT** to add in VBA i am using:

```
Sub SliceNDice() 
Dim objRegex As Object 
Dim X 
Dim Y 
Dim lngRow As Long 
Dim lngCnt As Long 
Dim tempArr() As String 
Dim strArr 
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") 
objRegex.Pattern = "^\s+(.+?)$" 
 'Define the range to be analysed
X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2 
Redim Y(1 To 2, 1 To 1000) 
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1) 
     'Split each string by ","
    tempArr = Split(X(lngRow, 2), ",") 
    For Each strArr In tempArr 
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 1 
         'Add another 1000 records to resorted array every 1000 records
        If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then Redim Preserve Y(1 To 2, 1 To lngCnt + 1000) 
        Y(1, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 1) 
        Y(2, lngCnt) = objRegex.Replace(strArr, "$1") 
    Next 
Next lngRow 
 'Dump the re-ordered range to columns C:D
[c1].Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y) 
End Sub
```

Do let me know if you need any other details, thank you in advance :-)

Comment: +1 for the well written question. I would encourage you to write out the algorithm (in plain text) and try to get some pieces of VBA code from online resources and put them together. When you get stuck, you can update your question with your specific point... That will attract lot of attention!

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. So as Prasanna suggested, share what you have already tried and are currently working with. We will try to help with that specifically.

Answer (score 1):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, running this short macro will produce the desired output in columns **C** through **E**

```
Sub reorg()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    Dim K As Long, KK As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1

    For i = 1 To N
        prod = Cells(i, 1).Value
        ary = Split(Cells(i, 2).Value, ", ")
        For KK = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            Cells(K, 3).Value = prod
            Cells(K, 4).Value = ary(KK)
            Cells(K, 5).Value = KK + 1
            K = K + 1
        Next KK
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have couple of mins to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45463/chat-with-garys-student)

Comment: This works like a dream and a lot more succinct than the code i was using!

Comment: Thank you....I like your approach, but I have never mastered Regular Expressions..........like much of UNIX-based syntax it only sticks in my mind for a couple of hours.

Comment: Your's is cleaner and again thank you for the quick and accurate response :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a two part question.
This is the answer for the second part of the question.
How to count and update the number of times `PRODx`has appeared.
I have implemented your requirement using formulas (but feel free to try your hand with VBA)
[image]

The formula is `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)`. Enter the formula for your first row and just drag along the length of your data and your will be able to get the count of `PRODx`

Comment: Thank you Prasanna, if it wasn't for Gary's Students code i would have used this as i already had the data split i just didn't have the sequence!